Linear regression: $\hat{u}$ vs. $u$
I am studying statistics as a major and got some confusion watching $\hat{u}$ and $u$.
My professor said $\hat{u}$ is called a residual and $u$ is an unobservable error term.
Therefore this is what I understood and I hope you can tell me if there is anything wrong.
We make the following assumptions by several samples.
$$
\hat{Y}_i = \hat{β}_0 + \hat{β}_1 X_i + \hat{u_i}
$$
And we make $E(\hat{u}_i^2) = 0$ by FOC.
This is the real model that we are making:
$$
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + u_i
$$
And we assume $E(u_i|X_i) = 0$ if there remains no other omitted variables.
Am I on the right page?

Could you please define FOC?

I meant first order condition

The FOC should be $\textrm{E}\left[\widehat{u}_{i}\right]=0$.  Otherwise, your understanding appears correct.  (Keep in mind that terms such as "residual", "error", "noise", etc. often are used imprecisely -- and even interchangeably -- in informal settings.)
